# File is getting locked on read/write operation in C#

Tags: windows, c#-4.0

A third party application is reading the output text file of my windows application,it is getting paused.I think,it is happening because of file gets locked either on writing or reading.how can i make this work fine.Please see my code.

```
    List<string> fileList = new List<string>();

    System.Timers.Timer timer;

    string currentfilename;
    string currentcontent;

    public Service1()
    {
```

//

```
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        timer.AutoReset = false;



        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(DoStuff);

    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void DoStuff(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {


     DateTime LastChecked = DateTime.Now;
     try
     {
         string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Journal", "*.jrn", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

         foreach (string file in files)
         {
             if (!fileList.Contains(file))
             {
                 currentfilename = file;
                 fileList.Add(file);

                     copywarehouse(file);


                 try
                 {


                         string sourcePath = @"C:\Journal";
                         string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, file);
                         using (FileStream fs= new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                         {
                             StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
                             currentcontent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                             sr.Close();

                         }


                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {

                     throw (ex);

                 }


         }


         }

         try
             {


                     string sourcePath1 = @"C:\Journal";
             string currentfilecontent;
                     string sourceFile1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath1, currentfilename);

                     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourceFile1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                     {
                         StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
                         currentfilecontent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                         sr.Close();

                     }





                     if (currentfilecontent != currentcontent)
                     {
                         if (currentfilecontent.Contains(currentcontent))
                         {
                             string originalcontent = currentfilecontent.Substring(currentcontent.Length);


                                 File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Journal\tempfile.txt", originalcontent + "\r\n");
                              using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Journal\tempfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.Write(originalcontent);
                sw.Close();
            }

                             currentcontent = currentfilecontent;
                         }
                     }



                 }
             //}

                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {

                     throw (ex);
                 }

         TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(LastChecked);
         TimeSpan MaxWaitTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);


         if (MaxWaitTime.Subtract(ts).CompareTo(TimeSpan.Zero) > -1)
             timer.Interval = MaxWaitTime.Subtract(ts).Milliseconds;
         else
             timer.Interval = 1;

         timer.Start();



     }



     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw (ex);
     }










    }
    private void copywarehouse(string filename)
    {
        string sourcePath = @"C:\Journal";
        string targetPath = @"C:\Journal";

        string copycontent=null;
        try
        {
            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, filename);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, "tempfile.txt");


            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
               StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

                copycontent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();


            }

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(destFile, FileMode.Append))
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.Write(copycontent);
                sw.Close();
            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }




    }
```

Comment: Impossible to answer this question.

Comment: There could be a million reasons why this is happening.

Comment: my application should copy contents from newly updated/created file in directory with extension .jrn to a textfile.this text file is reading by an application called POS text Sender.The above written code does its work perfectly,but POS Text Sender will get stopped reading from the middle.Can you tell me how can i make this application in other way if above code cant achieve its target..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is with third party application which is reading my application output as input.it is not allowing access to more than one file content..